# Given a string s, return the longest palindromic substring in s. c++ have problem with my attempt;

Tags: c++

> my attempt was trying to use find form aba / aa to compare each time, but it has some weird edge case , for example, the case "aaaa" was working fine, but "aaaaa" return only "aaaa" was incorrect.
> I knew watching the discussion to find the answer for this, but I really want to know where I got wrong with my algorithm and see how can I improve this.

```
string longestPalindrome(string s) {
    if(s.size() == 1)return s;
    if(s.size() == 2 &&s[0]!= s[1]){
        string x ="";
        x+=s[0];
        return x;
    }
    if(s.size() == 2 &&s[0]== s[1])return s;
    if(s.size() == 3  && s[0]== s[2])return s;
    string ans="";
    ans+=s[0];//avoid to_string
    
    for(int i =0; i < s.size();i++){ //c i=1 bb
        string temp="";
        if(s[i] == s[i+1]){//aa
            temp+=s[i];
            temp+=s[i+1];
            int prev = i-1;
            int curr = i+2;//   scaacw  caac
            while(prev-1 != 0 && curr != s.size()){
                if(prev== curr){
                    string x="";
                    x+=s[prev];
                    temp.insert(0,x);
                    temp+=s[curr];
                    x = "";
                }else
                    break;
                prev--;
                curr++;
            }
            if(s[0]==s[s.size()-1]){
                    string x="";
                    x+=s[0];
                    temp.insert(0,x);
                    temp+=s[s.size()-1];
            }
            if(temp.size()>ans.size()){
                 ans = temp;
                temp = "";
        }
        }
        else if(s[i] == s[i+2]){//i =3
            temp+=s[i];
            temp+=s[i+1];
            temp+=s[i+2];
            int prev = i-1;
            int curr = i+3;
            while(prev-1 != 0 && curr != s.size()){
                if(prev== curr){
                    string x="";
                    x+=s[prev];
                    temp.insert(0,x);
                    temp+=s[curr];
                    x = "";
                }else                       
                    break;
                prev--;
                curr++;
                }
                if(s[0]==s[s.size()-1]){
                    string x="";
                    x+=s[0];
                    temp.insert(0,x);
                    temp+=s[s.size()-1];
            }
            if(temp.size()>ans.size()){
                 ans = temp;
                 temp = "";
        }
        } 
        
            
            
    }
 
      return ans;  
    }
```

};

Answer (score 0):

So the first problem that you also wrote was that you get "aaaa" instead of "aaaaa". That is because in your for loop, in the first if statement, you check for "aa", so 2 same characters next to eacht other. Then you try something, I guess to go "left" and "right" in the string. But this "if(prev== curr)" does not make much sense, I think you wanted to write "s[prev]" and "s[curr]", because I am not sure how they could ever be equal. Nonetheless, another problem is that when you are looking for the "aa" in the string, you do not find the "middle" "aa", but the first "aa". Then you check if the first letter, which is "a" and the last letter, which is "a" as well are the same. They are, so you add it to your string, hence the "aaaa". If you run it for "1aabc1" it will give you "1aa1", because of the same reasons. You find "aa", then you check if the first equals the last, and you add it.

I think it is a good brain exercise to write these things on your own, but you are not on the correct track yet.

To maybe help a bit, your approach seems to be building the palindrome. So you are not taking substrings and checking, but trying to build it up. You see that correctly, that either you are looking for an "aba"-like or an "aa"-like palindrome. I tried to follow your logic, and came up with the following function:

```
std::string longestPalindrome2(const std::string& s) {
    
    size_t max_palindrome_length = 0;
    int max_palindrome_start = 0;
    
    for (int i = 0; i < s.size(); ++i) {
        int down = i - 1;
        int up = i + 1;
        while (down >= 0 && up < s.size()) {
            if (s[down] == s[up]) {
                int substring_size = up - down + 1;
                if (max_palindrome_length < substring_size) {
                    max_palindrome_length = substring_size;
                    max_palindrome_start = down;
                }
            }
            else break;
            --down;
            ++up;
        }
        
        down = i;
        up = i + 1;
        while (down >= 0 && up < s.size()) {
            if (s[down] == s[up]) {
                int substring_size = up - down + 1;
                if (max_palindrome_length < substring_size) {
                    max_palindrome_length = substring_size;
                    max_palindrome_start = down;
                }
            }
            else break;
            --down;
            ++up;
        }
    }
    
    std::string substring = s.substr(max_palindrome_start, max_palindrome_length);
    if (substring.empty()) substring = s.substr(0, 1);
    std::cout << "substring '" << substring << "' IS a palindrome " << std::endl;
    return substring;
}
```

I tried to do what you did, so building up the palindrome by checking the lower and upper neighbours. Although I am not a 100% sure if this is correct, it seems to work with my test cases.

I also wrote another function, which follows a "top-down" approach instead of your "bottom-up" one. With the test cases, the whole code looks like this:

```
bool is_it_palindrome(const std::string& str) {
    /* loop through the string until the middle is reached */
    for (int i = 0; i < str.size() / 2; ++i) {
        /* if the mirrored pairs are not the same, it is not a palindrome */
        if (str[i] != str[str.size() - 1 - i]) return false;
    }
    /* all mirrored pairs were the same */
    return true;
}

std::string longestPalindrome(const std::string& s) {

    /* the first substring will be the whole string itself */
    int substring_size = s.size();
    
    /* loop and reduce the substring size in each iteration */
    /* so if we assume a string of size 5, we fist take all the possible */
    /* 5 long substrings (only one such substring exists, the whole string) */
    /* then we take the 4 long substrings, there are 2 of them, then the 3 */
    /* long substrings, etc */
    while (substring_size > 0) {
        /* loop through the characters and get the substring from each character */
        /* then check if this substring is a palindrome */
        /* since we are looping from the largest substring possible to smaller ones */
        /* it will definitely find the largest on first */
        for (int i = 0; i < s.size(); ++i) {
            if (i + substring_size <= s.size()) {
                std::string substring = s.substr(i, substring_size);
                if (is_it_palindrome(substring)) {
                    std::cout << "substring '" << substring << "' IS a palindrome " << std::endl;
                    return substring;
                }
                //std::cout << "substring '" << substring << "' is NOT a palindrome " << std::endl;
            }
        }
        --substring_size;
    }
    
    return ""; 
}

std::string longestPalindrome2(const std::string& s) {
    
    size_t max_palindrome_length = 0;
    int max_palindrome_start = 0;
    
    for (int i = 0; i < s.size(); ++i) {
        /* search for the "aba" style palindrome */
        int down = i - 1;
        int up = i + 1;
        while (down >= 0 && up < s.size()) {
            if (s[down] == s[up]) {
                int substring_size = up - down + 1;
                if (max_palindrome_length < substring_size) {
                    max_palindrome_length = substring_size;
                    max_palindrome_start = down;
                }
            }
            else break;
            --down;
            ++up;
        }
        
        /* search for the "aa" style palindrome */
        down = i;
        up = i + 1;
        while (down >= 0 && up < s.size()) {
            if (s[down] == s[up]) {
                int substring_size = up - down + 1;
                if (max_palindrome_length < substring_size) {
                    max_palindrome_length = substring_size;
                    max_palindrome_start = down;
                }
            }
            else break;
            --down;
            ++up;
        }
    }
    
    std::string substring = s.substr(max_palindrome_start, max_palindrome_length);
    if (substring.empty()) substring = s.substr(0, 1);
    std::cout << "substring '" << substring << "' IS a palindrome " << std::endl;
    return substring;
}

int main() {
    longestPalindrome("aaaaa");
    longestPalindrome2("aaaaa");
    std::cout << "----------------------------------------------" << std::endl;
    longestPalindrome("1aabc1");
    longestPalindrome2("1aabc1");
    std::cout << "----------------------------------------------" << std::endl;
    longestPalindrome("21");
    longestPalindrome2("21");
    std::cout << "----------------------------------------------" << std::endl;
    longestPalindrome("2asddsa1");
    longestPalindrome2("2asddsa1");
    std::cout << "----------------------------------------------" << std::endl;
    longestPalindrome("a");
    longestPalindrome2("a");
    std::cout << "----------------------------------------------" << std::endl;
    longestPalindrome("abcdefgh");
    longestPalindrome2("abcdefgh");

    return 0;
}
```

And the results are the following:

```
substring 'aaaaa' IS a palindrome 
substring 'aaaaa' IS a palindrome 
----------------------------------------------
substring 'aa' IS a palindrome 
substring 'aa' IS a palindrome 
----------------------------------------------
substring '2' IS a palindrome 
substring '2' IS a palindrome 
----------------------------------------------
substring 'asddsa' IS a palindrome 
substring 'asddsa' IS a palindrome 
----------------------------------------------
substring 'a' IS a palindrome 
substring 'a' IS a palindrome 
----------------------------------------------
substring 'a' IS a palindrome 
substring 'a' IS a palindrome
```

Comment: Thank you so much for replying me, my algorithm was trying to get thing done by loop, if you see my while loop, that I check if is "aabc' or if is 'aaabc' thing, also, my point was trying to use temp string to hold aba or bb and compare the size of them... thank you so much again for the first example, it really solve the problem by what I thought.

Comment: I practice leetcode for like 100+ez and trying to get some mid questions....but I find out im so lost at this time.....

Comment: You are welcome, I am glad I could help. Ask as many questions as you want, that is why this forum was made for :)